# Undefined index in Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle/Guesser/FilterTypeGuesser.php while configuring Datagrid Filters wihin SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

i'm trying to use datagrid filters with my simple entity:

// MyBundle/Entity/Application.php

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="application")
 */
class Application extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer $_id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $_id;

    /**
     * @var string $_name
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=1000)
     */
    protected $_name;

    public function __toString()
    {
        if ((string) $this->_id === '') {
            return "N/A";
        }
        return $this->_name;
    }

    /**
     * Set _id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->_id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Get _id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set _name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get _name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }
}
```

// MyBundle/Admin/ApplicationAdmin.php

```
class ApplicationAdmin extends Admin
{
    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @param string $class
     * @param string $baseControllerName
     */
    public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName)
    {
        parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);
        $this->setMaxPerPage(25);
    }

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('id', 'integer')
            ->add('name', 'text')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('name');
        ;
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id', null, array('label' => 'ID'))
            ->addIdentifier('name', null, array('label' => 'Name'))
        ;
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to get list of applications I get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in /path-to-symfony-project/vendor/bundles/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle/Guesser/FilterTypeGuesser.php line 65
```

If change the **configureDatagridFilters** function code to:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('name', 'doctrine_orm_string');
    ;
}
```

I get the applications list with requested filter successfully, but when I try to submit the filters form  with some data (i.e. Name contains aaa) I get another error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 87 near 'name LIKE :n': Error: Class MyBundle\Entity\Application has no field or association named name
```

If change the **configureDatagridFilters** function code to:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('_name');
        //or
        //->add('_name', 'doctrine_orm_string');
    ;
}
```

I get the applications list with requested filter also successfully, but when I try to submit the filters form with some data (i.e. Name contains aaa) I get the third error:

```
Invalid parameter format, : given, but :<name> or ?<num> expected.
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
```

I have no ideas, please, help.

Comment: But if I remove the underscores within fields names - everything works, but I need the underscores - company format for protected properties.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe it's time to change old company`s coding style to [PSR-1 Basic Coding Standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) and  [PSR-2-coding-style-guide](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) for all your Symfony2 applications.

Using undescores for private/protected properties is deprecated and was valueable only for old PHP4 projects where no private and protected methods exist. 
**It`s not good to mix different coding styles in one application**. All Symfony bundles are using PSR standards and [Symfony standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html).